# Delay node js execution at a specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I use this script:

```
var i = 0;
async.whilst(
    // test to perform next iteration
    function() { return i <= Myobject.length-1; },
    function(innerCallback){
//Some calculations....
setTimeout(function() { i++; innerCallback(); }, 10000);
  };
);
```

The snippet above delays the execution between loop elements for 10 seconds. But how could I delay the loop execution at a `specific time` for a number of seconds?
Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "specific time"? Like the system time?

Comment: @AlexFord Like each 30 minutes, for example 00.30,01.00,01.30 and so on

Comment: Well you could just make the timeout be 1800000 milliseconds, which is equal to 30 minutes. You could use `setInterval` for a timeout that keeps recurring.

Comment: if you subtract one date from another, you're left with the difference in ms, which coincidentally, is the input setTimeout expects. so, `setTimeout(doSomething, new Date(2021,4,3) - Date.now())`

Comment: @AlexFord Ok, but my question was that I want to set the pause of,say, 30 seconds after 30 minutes! And go on like that :)

Comment: @dandavis Any suggestions about o set the pause of,say, 30 seconds after 30 minutes? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var delayInterval = 10000;

setTimeout(function(){
  delayInterval = 30000;
}, 1000*60*30);

var i = 0;
async.whilst(
    // test to perform next iteration
    function() { return i <= Myobject.length-1; },
    function(innerCallback){
//Some calculations....
setTimeout(function() { i++; innerCallback(); }, delayInterval );
  };
);
```

Comment: Could you please explain briefly? Will the above example delay each 30 minutes, for 10 seconds? Best  Regards

Comment: It does what you asked for, it sets the pause (delayInterval) to 30 seconds after 30 minutes, up from the initial value of 10 seconds. If the routine ends before 30 minutes, this will have no effect.